# int to unknown to double conversion issue

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, dll, type-conversion

I created a program to read/write with data from another program. I set a value of 7 (of type memory real) in the program, then when I read the value in visual studio, it gives me a string `7.0000000000000`. So I created this conversion snippet which works for data of type int which also gives me a string in VS. I don't know the difference between these 2 data types but logically if both data types give me a **string**, I should be able to run this code. Why the memory real data skips the if here?

```
 if (Regex.IsMatch(value, "^[0-9 ]+$"))
                {
                    ValueBox.Text = Double.Parse(value).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    ValueBox.Text = value;
                }
```

EDIT: I use 2 given dlls, I believe there is a conversion issue in the dll but my code should *still* work.

EDIT 2: This code is a section from my program, value and other variables are already defined

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce this locally in the function?  i.e. declare and initialize `value` prior to the condition?  That might help see what the problem is.

Comment: You are allowing a space in the regex.

Comment: @Blam could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skip the Regex and use TryParse

[Double.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx)

[Int32.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

or can just format "N0"

d.ToString("N0")

Comment: Nice...  It's always the simple solutions that work the best.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space in your regex after the number range, but that shouldn't be too much of a problem.  The way it is written, your regex will match any sequence of numbers or spaces.

This would match an integer string only:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(value, "^[0-9]+$"))
...
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem based on the initialization of `value`, but it certainly won't match an integer string.

If you need to account for decimal values in your regex:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(value, "^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$"))
...
```

Comment: I  forgot to mention.

Before, I always had ex: program int = 5 gave me a string of 5.00000. My code works and it converts the string to 5, but for this other type, it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not clearly describe where `value` comes from.

I suspect you should be using one of the overloaded `.ToString()` methods to convert the original data type to `value`.
Then to convert `ValueBox.Text` back use `Convert.ToDouble()` (or appropriate method for the desired output type).  You could also use `Double.TryParse()` (or appropriate type) which I prefer.

References:
[Double.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[Double.TryParse Method (String, Double%)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx)